# Insert into select query for below requirement

Tags: sql

For the below requirement please provide the INSERT INTO SELECT query to proceed further. I am new to SQL.

I need to copy one row from Table_A, and need to insert same row in same table. But, some of the values from the copied row, I need to modify.

TABLE_A:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| RAVI | KIRAN |

From the above tale 'TABLE_A', I want to copy the row(FIRST_NAME=RAVI,LAST_NAME=KIRAN) and need to insert in the same table 'TABLE_A' with values FIRST_NAME=Krishna, LAST_NAME=KIRAN.

NOTE: FIRST_NAME column from TABLE_A is a unique constraint.

Required output:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| RAVI | KIRAN |
| KRISHNA | KIRAN |

---

Please find the details below.

TABLE_B

| RULEKEY | RULESET |
| --- | --- |
| 823450 | 1 |

I have a TABE_B like above, I have to get next sequence value in RULEKEY column from TABLE_B, and need to pass that next sequence value as a parameter to the column 'FIRST_NAME' in TABLE_A while inserting data.

Required output:

For example if next sequence value for RULEKEY column from TABLE_B is '823451' the required output needed is

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| RAVI | KIRAN |
| 823451 | KIRAN |

I tried the below query, but I am notified with below error.

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
SELECT (SELECT SCHEMA.RULEKEY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL), LAST_NAME
FROM  TABLE_A
WHERE FIRST_NAME='RAVI'
AND LAST_NAME='KIRAN'

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
*Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the sequence number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
SELECT 'KRISHNA', LAST_NAME
FROM  TABLE_A 
WHERE FIRST_NAME='RAVI'
AND LAST_NAME='KIRAN'
```

Just list the other columns you want to insert on the first line, and on the SELECT

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, OTHER_COLs...)
SELECT 'KRISHNA', LAST_NAME, OTHER_COLs...
FROM  TABLE_A 
WHERE FIRST_NAME='RAVI'
AND LAST_NAME='KIRAN'
```

You can also get values from other table(s):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, OTHER_COLs...)
SELECT OTHER_FIRST_NAME, OTHER_LAST_LAST_NAME, OTHER_COLs...
FROM  TABLE_B
WHERE Criteria for selecting from Table_B
```

It seems that you can't use a subquery invoking .NEXTVAL for a sequence. Why don't you invoke directly:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) 
SELECT SCHEMA.RULEKEY.NEXTVAL, LAST_NAME 
FROM TABLE_A WHERE FIRST_NAME='RAVI' AND LAST_NAME='KIRAN'
```

Admittedly I don't understand why you want to insert a number into a character column holding FIRST_NAME.

Comment: Please acept it as answer then!

Comment: Hi tinazmu,     

From below query, If I want to get 'Krishna' value from other table by using select query, How we need to modify the query. Could you please help me to proceed further.

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
SELECT 'KRISHNA', LAST_NAME
FROM  TABLE_A 
WHERE FIRST_NAME='RAVI'
AND LAST_NAME='KIRAN'

Comment: You need to provide more information: which table is it in? How is that table related to this table?

Comment: I have updated the required details in the Requirement question..

Comment: Its working now with the query you provided. Thank you...!!!